# full screen background image (sort of) - without cropping?

Tags: css, background-image

My client wants what may in fact be impossible - they want a full screen background image that doesn't crop, and that retains its dimensions. They are willing to accept white space, but they want the image to fill the screen as best it can without cropping on any axis. I was able to find nice scripts that achieve true full page backgrounds, but they won't accept any cropping of the image. Any ideas?

Comment: Make a background image that tiles?

Comment: what about css background-cover?

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<img id="bg" src="whateves.jpg"/>
```

you might want to center the image in css

```
#bg { display:block; margin:auto; }
```

using jquery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
      var windowRezize = function() {
          var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
              bg = $('#bg'),
              bgHeight = bg.height();

            console.log(windowHeight);
            console.log (bgHeight);
          bg.height($(window).height());
          bg.css('opacity', '1');
      };
      windowRezize();
      $(window).resize(function(){
          console.log('resized');
          windowRezize();
      })

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not impossible! You can totally do this. Use JQuery to find the height and width of the browser viewport and voila! Set background image to that size. If you need to maintain aspect, use a JQuery algorithm for width/height, use that ratio to benchmark against the ratio of the actual dimensions and if it's higher/lower set the height/width of the background image to 100% and the other dimension to whatever the actual ratio would calculate it to be.

If your client doesn't care about scroll bars you can follow this guide under the third attempt:
http://css-tricks.com/766-how-to-resizeable-background-image/ And set the minimum height of the html/body element to whatever it needs to be according to the width of the background image. I hope this all helps you get ideas for what to do.

Comment: I tried the CSS technique listed on css-tricks (the third one) but it crops on whatever axis isn't constrained. All the techniques on that page require cropping, from what I tried. I guess I need to use a Jquery method.. was trying to avoid it because I'm not that brilliant with it. Any published methods out there that you are familiar with that use jQuery?

Comment: With JQuery you can simply use $(window).width() and I'm sure you can use the same kind of function to get the height. Use those two to find the aspect ratio of the browser window and then from there choose which (height or width) of your background image should be maximized to fill the screen and then set the width of the background image. I don't remember if the height of a background image can be set in CSS, but you can set a div element to be your "body" and set it's height to the browser heigt and set it to display: fixed and keep it's z-index lower than everything else

Comment: Also, like I said, if your client doesn't care about having cheesy scrollbars you can set the minimum height of the html/body to the height required to show the whole image via scrolling. But again you might have to use JQuery to figure out the width of the browser first